# npm install errors with window's CMD

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes, mean-stack, npm-install

I'm new to NODEjs trying to globally in using window 8.1 **run as ADMINISTRATOR from CMD**

> **install an npm module i.e. node-dev**

Every time I try to npm install I get this error.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600

npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "node-dev"

npm ERR! node v6.10.1

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.nmpjs.org registry.nmpjs.org:80

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network setti
gs.
npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I did some searching around, and saw a couple of similar cases none of which have been resolved for the case of windows.

So what's the deal? Is this some weird fringe case bug that has no solution yet?

Comment: The argv error shows invalid WIndows pathspec   "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"  -- try using the single backslash argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" -- and of course, check if the expected files are in the expected place.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
npm cache clean
```

then

```
npm install -g <package_name>
```

If this does not work

```
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

and try, installing the package.